# Byte to Binary String C# - Display all 8 digits

Tags: c#, .net, string, byte, bit

I want to display one byte in textbox.
Now I'm using:

```
Convert.ToString(MyVeryOwnByte, 2);
```

But when byte is has 0's at begining those 0's are being cut.
Example:

```
MyVeryOwnByte = 00001110 // Texbox shows -> 1110
MyVeryOwnByte = 01010101 // Texbox shows -> 1010101
MyVeryOwnByte = 00000000 // Texbox shows -> <Empty>
MyVeryOwnByte = 00000001 // Texbox shows -> 1
```

I want to display all 8 digits.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644609/c-problem-with-byte and specifically http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644609/c-problem-with-byte/1644666#1644666

Comment: As the code in this question has already [been misunderstood by another user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22894695/preceding-0s-in-integer-value), it should be pointed out that `MyVeryOwnByte` is not actually a `byte` here, and that (if that is the actual C# code used) literals such as `01010101` are *decimal* numbers (that happen to consist of only zeroes and ones); the actual bits of the bytes making up those numbers look quite a bit different.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper It is only "pseudocode".

Comment: @Hooch: Ok, then only the author of the [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22894695/preceding-0s-in-integer-value) was possibly mistaken.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert an integer to a binary string with leading zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23905188/convert-an-integer-to-a-binary-string-with-leading-zeros)

Answer (score 77, accepted):

```
Convert.ToString(MyVeryOwnByte, 2).PadLeft(8, '0');
```

This will fill the empty space to the left with '0' for a total of 8 characters in the string

Answer (score 13):

How you do it depends on how you want your output to look.

If you just want "00011011", use a function like this:

```
static string Pad(byte b)
{
    return Convert.ToString(b, 2).PadLeft(8, '0');
}
```

If you want output like "000**11011**", use a function like this:

```
static string PadBold(byte b)
{
    string bin = Convert.ToString(b, 2);
    return new string('0', 8 - bin.Length) + "<b>" + bin + "</b>";
}
```

If you want output like "0001 1011", a function like this might be better:

```
static string PadNibble(byte b)
{
    return Int32.Parse(Convert.ToString(b, 2)).ToString("0000 0000");
}
```

Comment: @Jeff: I posted this version because sometimes the `new string()` technique is useful. You didn't question Gregory's mention of `PadRight`, and that function doesn't even solve the problem.

Comment: How I reacted to someone else's response is entirely irrelevant. I just thought it strange to see you downplay your answer by referring to a better solution that you didn't give and that the suggestion you had was not particular easy to read. As SO is a resource for getting a good answer, you'd be better including the PadLeft solution entirely AND your alternative - you might well be the better answer then. This isn't about first, it's about best.

Comment: @Jeff: I prefer a separate post for each answer so that one can easily browse answers without having to wade through duplicates. However, I have made an exception today, and just for you have put 3 answers into a single post.

Comment: The third answer was almost approximately what I was looking for.  The pattern I needed was 00 00 00 00 ... i think i figured it out :)

Answer (score 1):

Pad the string with zeros. In this case it is `PadLeft(length, characterToPadWith)`. Very useful extension methods. `PadRight()` is another useful method.

Comment: `PadRight` is a useful method but not in this scenario. I recommend you remove that from your answer (or add every other useful .NET method - I know which I'd pick :D).

Comment: Also, they're not extension methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an extension method:

```
public static class ByteExtension
{
    public static string ToBitsString(this byte value)
    {
        return Convert.ToString(value, 2).PadLeft(8, '0');
    }
}
```