# Convert an integer to a binary string with leading zeros

Tags: c#, binary

I need to convert int to bin and with extra bits.

```
string aaa = Convert.ToString(3, 2);
```

it returns `11`, but I need `0011`, or `00000011`.

How is it done?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

`11` is [binary representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number#Representation) of `3`. The binary representation of this value is `2` bits.

3 = 2<sup>0</sup> * 1 + 2<sup>1</sup> * 1

You can use [`String.PadLeft(Int, Char)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to add these zeros.

```
// convert number 3 to binary string. 
// And pad '0' to the left until string will be not less then 4 characters
Convert.ToString(3, 2).PadLeft(4, '0') // 0011
Convert.ToString(3, 2).PadLeft(8, '0') // 00000011
```

Comment: what if the number is changing. like for example I am reading a file and converting the decimals in this file to binary (8bits each). In this case the number of zeros will be different from decimal to decimal.

Answer (score 3):

You can use these methods:

```
public static class BinaryExt
{
    public static string ToBinary(this int number, int bitsLength = 32)
    {
        return NumberToBinary(number, bitsLength);
    }

    public static string NumberToBinary(int number, int bitsLength = 32)
    {
        string result = Convert.ToString(number, 2).PadLeft(bitsLength, '0');

        return result;
    }

    public static int FromBinaryToInt(this string binary)
    {   
        return BinaryToInt(binary);
    }

    public static int BinaryToInt(string binary)
    {   
        return Convert.ToInt32(binary, 2);
    }   
}
```

Sample:

```
int number = 3; 
string byte3 = number.ToBinary(8); // output: 00000011

string bits32 = BinaryExt.NumberToBinary(3); // output: 00000000000000000000000000000011
```

Answer (score 3):

I've created a method to dynamically write leading zeroes

```
public static string ToBinary(int myValue)
{
      string binVal = Convert.ToString(myValue, 2);
      int bits = 0;
      int bitblock = 4;

      for (int i = 0; i < binVal.Length; i = i + bitblock)
      { bits += bitblock; }

      return binVal.PadLeft(bits, '0');
}
```

At first we convert my value to binary.
Initializing the bits to set the length for binary output.
One Bitblock has 4 Digits. In for-loop we check the length of our converted binary value und adds the "bits" for the length for binary output.

Examples:
Input: 1 -> 0001;
Input: 127 -> 01111111
etc....

Answer (score 2):

Since .NET 8+ you can do it simply by using the method `ToString()`:

```cs
string s;
s = 42.ToString("b");        // .NET8+ => "101010".
s = Convert.ToString(42, 2); // .NET Framework 2+ to .NET7 => "101010".

s = 42.ToString("b16");                       // .NET8+ => "0000000000101010".
s = Convert.ToString(42, 2).PadLeft(16, '0'); // .NET Framework 2+ to .NET7 => "0000000000101010".
```

Source: [Microsoft: Standard format specifiers .NET8+](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings)

Answer (score 1):

Just what Soner answered use:

```
Convert.ToString(3, 2).PadLeft(4, '0')
```

Just want to add just for you to know. The int parameter is the total number of characters that your string and the char parameter is the character that will be added to fill the lacking space in your string. In your example, you want the output 0011 which which is 4 characters and needs 0's thus you use 4 as int param and '0' in char.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String HexToBinString(this String value)
{
        String binaryString = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(value, 16), 2);
        Int32 zeroCount = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(Convert.ToDouble(binaryString.Length) / 8)) * 8;

        return binaryString.PadLeft(zeroCount, '0');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the most elegant solution but it is the fastest from my testing:

```c
string IntToBinary(int value, int totalDigits) {
    char[] output = new char[totalDigits];
    int diff = sizeof(int) * 8 - totalDigits;
    for (int n = 0; n != totalDigits; ++n) {
        output[n] = (char)('0' + (char)((((uint)value << (n + diff))) >> (sizeof(int) * 8 - 1)));
    }
    return new string(output);
}
string LongToBinary(int value, int totalDigits) {
    char[] output = new char[totalDigits];
    int diff = sizeof(long) * 8 - totalDigits;
    for (int n = 0; n != totalDigits; ++n) {
        output[n] = (char)('0' + (char)((((ulong)value << (n + diff))) >> (sizeof(long) * 8 - 1)));
    }
    return new string(output);
}
```

This version completely avoids if statements and therfore branching which creates very fast and most importantly linear code. This beats the Convert.ToString() function from microsoft by up to 50%

Here is some benchmark code

```c
long testConv(Func<int, int, string> fun, int value, int digits, long avg) {
    long result = 0;
    for (long n = 0; n < avg; n++) {
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        fun(value, digits);
        result += sw.ElapsedTicks;
    }
    Console.WriteLine((string)fun(value, digits));
    return result / (avg / 100);//for bigger output values
}
string IntToBinary(int value, int totalDigits) {
    char[] output = new char[totalDigits];
    int diff = sizeof(int) * 8 - totalDigits;
    for (int n = 0; n != totalDigits; ++n) {
        output[n] = (char)('0' + (char)((((uint)value << (n + diff))) >> (sizeof(int) * 8 - 1)));
    }
    return new string(output);
}
string Microsoft(int value, int totalDigits) {
    return Convert.ToString(value, toBase: 2).PadLeft(totalDigits, '0');
}

int v = 123, it = 10000000;
Console.WriteLine(testConv(Microsoft, v, 10, it));
Console.WriteLine(testConv(IntToBinary, v, 10, it));
```

Here are my results

```
0001111011
122
0001111011
75
```

Microsofts Method takes 1.22 ticks while mine only takes 0.75 ticks

Answer (score 0):

```
string aaa = Convert.ToString(3, 2).PadLeft(10, '0');
```

Comment: Got flagged for length+content - presumably because there is no explanation.

Comment: This was the first post with the answer. This answer is self-explanatory in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

With this you can get binary representation of string with corresponding leading zeros.

```
string binaryString = Convert.ToString(3, 2);;
int myOffset = 4;
string modified = binaryString.PadLeft(binaryString.Length % myOffset == 0 ? binaryString.Length : binaryString.Length + (myOffset - binaryString.Length % myOffset), '0'));
```

In your case modified string will be `0011`, if you want you can change offset to 8, for instance, and you will get `00000011` and so on.