# Convert integer into binary string without losing zeros

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, string, binaries

I need to convert a whole in binary, my problem is that if I have 011001, I find myself at the end of the conversion 111. How can I leave the zeros? and maintain so the conversion as it should be.
Thank you.

```
 int value = 8388607;
 String bin = Convert.ToString(value, 2);
```

**SOLUTION**:

```
String bin = Convert.ToString(value, 2).PadLeft(X,'0');
```

where x is the number of bits that make up the string

Comment: is not the same question, he asks for conversion, I wonder how leave 0 in the conversion.

Comment: I've reopened the question: I agree with Mr. Developer, it's not just a conversion.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert an integer to a binary string with leading zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23905188/convert-an-integer-to-a-binary-string-with-leading-zeros)

Answer (score 3):

`PadLeft()` should do it

```
     int value = 8388607;
     String bin = Convert.ToString(value, 2).PadLeft(32, '0');
```

Change 32 to how many bits you would like the number to show

Comment: How is this different from what is already written as the solution?

Comment: It's not, OP edited in the solution while I added my answer. Got posted together