# How to convert Decimal to binary C# (4 bits)

Tags: c#, binary, decimal

i want to convert Decimal numbers to binary, 
Currently I'm using this way

```
private string strtoBin(string input)
{
    int number = Convert.ToInt32(input) ;
    string res = Convert.ToString(number, 2);

    return res;
}
```

it's working but when I'm having for example "6" I'm getting 110 instead of 0110? 
Any tips?!

Comment: `"6" I'm getting 110 instead of 0110` Why not `00000110` or ...

Comment: My bad, only 4 bits not more :) 0110 @HamletHakobyan

Comment: `res = res.PadLeft(4,'0')`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829366/byte-to-binary-string-c-sharp-display-all-8-digits

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758196/convert-int-to-a-bit-array-in-net

Comment: Use the BitArray class as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758196/convert-int-to-a-bit-array-in-net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple string modification:

```
string res = Convert.ToString(number, 2);
res = new string('0', 8 - res.Length) + res;
```